# How find sampleCount knowing length audio file and sampleRate?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav

I have been looking for a long time how to find sampleCount, but there is no answer. It is possible to say an algorithm or formula for calculation. It is known 850ms , the file weight is 37 KB, the resolution of the wav file , sampleRate is 48000.... I can check , you should get sampleCount equal to 40681 as I have in the file . this is necessary so that I can calculate sampleCount for other audio files.I am waiting for your help

I found and I get 40800 . I multiplied the rate with the time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sample count is equal to the sample rate, multiplied by the duration.

So for an audio file that is exactly 850 milliseconds, at 48 kHz sample rate:

```
850 * 48000 = 40800 samples
```

Now, with MP3s you have to be careful.  There is some padding at the beginning of the file for cleanly initializing the decoder, and the amount of padding can vary based on the encoder and its configuration.  (You can read all about the troubles this has caused on the [Wikipedia page for "gapless playback"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapless_playback).)  Additionally, your MP3 duration will be determined on MP3 frame boundaries, and not arbitrary PCM boundaries... assuming your decoder/player does not support gapless playback.

Comment: Thanks! My result right,yeah? 40800 samples. You can use an example of the indentation itself as it is reflected in samples.